# Excel: Autofill sequential groups of formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, excel-auto-fill

I have groups of formulas in Excel 2016:

```
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B43
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B43
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B43
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B43
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B44
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B44
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B44
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B44
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B45
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B45
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B45
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B45
```

The formulas are repeated four times in each group.

I would like to autofill the next four rows (and so on):

```
...
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B46
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B46
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B46
=CLASSSTRUCTURE!B46
```

**Is there a way to do this?**

Comment: Use `INDIRECT()` based on `(ROW()+delta)/4`.

Comment: @Akina Thanks. I think someone will need to dumb that down for me. This was my attempt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNQgF.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use the INDEX() function that lets you look up a cell within a range of cells by giving it is row and column number.

Use something like this:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100, INT((ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))/4)+1)
```

where

$A$1:$A$100 is the range of cells you are referencing (it can down down as far as  you wish).

ROW() gives you row number of the cell it refers to, so ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1) gives us the number of cells down from the first cell we are filling. (Note the $'s)

Divide that by 4 and round down and we have gives us a line number of the cell we are taking data from. This formula can be copied down the page as far as you want.

It is possible to use "OFFSET" or "INDIRECT" functions in a similar way but they will make your spreadsheet much slower becuase they are both 'volatile' functions that can't take advantage of Excel's smart optimisations of the calculation process.

---

Optimisations:

We can reduce the number of uses of "INDEX" because 3 of every 4 cells are the same as the one above. So we use:

```
Cell     Formula
C1       =INDEX($A$1:$A$100, INT((ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))/4)+1)
C2       =C1
C3       =C2
C4       =C3
C5       =INDEX($A$1:$A$100, INT((ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))/4)+1)
C6       =C5
C7       ...
```

This can still be copy-pasted down the sheet so long as you only do so in blocks of 4 rows.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get `=INDEX($A$1:$A$100, INT((ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))/4)+1)` working (in column `B`) by putting a simple sequence of numbers in column `A` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsR49.jpg). Is that how you intended it to be done?

Comment: That is exactly what I intended.